# FFMPEG: Convert .rgb images to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, rgb

I want to create a video from .rgb files. These just contain the pixels, no header.

I'm able to cerate a video from pngs:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -i %%06d.png -vcodec huffyuv video.avi
```

But converting the .rgb files to png via ImageMagick (not surprisingly) takes ages.
When I try:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -s 1776x1000 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i %%06d.rgb -vcodec huffyuv video.avi

[image2 @ 0238d520] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[image2 @ 0238d520] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none, rgb24, 1776x1000): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options %06d.rgb: could not find codec parameters
```

Is there a way to directly feed rgb files to ffmpeg?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file?

Comment: I got it, I was lacking -vcodec rawvideo. But apparently I can't answer my own question in the first 8 hours ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-vcodec rawvideo
```

That's what I was lacking

```
fmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -s 1776x1000 -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -i %%06d.rgb -vcodec huffyuv video.avi
```

Works now.